# Shared prefence from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

My app have mainactivity
User must set a password and it saved in shared prefence like this

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("password", edpassstr);
editor.apply();
```

I can get this preference in another activity successfully
But I can't get it in the fragment
This is the code used to restore value from shared preference

```
settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("NAME", 0);
String  passs = settings.getString("password", "");
```

The string passs is ="" inside fragment. Why?
How to get the string from shared preference in a fragment?

Comment: What is this edpassstr ?

Comment: String from edittext

Comment: And are you sure it has a non-empty value?

Comment: Yes i am sure because it is a simple edittext

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare as a global variable

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

in onCreate() method declare as

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("password", "xyz_password");
editor.apply();
```

You can get the value from shared preference using this way

```
prefs.getString(key,default Value);
prefs.getString("password", "Any value if you not get any value");
```

It's so easy I hope it's helpful to you...!

Answer (score 0):

where are you calling getActivity() in your fragment? Because it will return null when it gets called before the fragment's onAttach method. In your fragment, try overriding the onAttach method, since it gets context as a parameter like so:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("NAME", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the shared preferences across the application. You should use applicationcontext instead of lifecycle owners (activity or fragments) context.

```
applicationcontext.getSharedPreferences(name, mode)
```